# Who can explain the 'Replication' in dynamo paper?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-replication

In dynamo paper : http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf

The Replication section said:

> To account for node failures, preference list contains more than N
>   nodes.

[image]

I want to know why ? and does this 'node' mean virtual node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is for increasing Dynamo availability. If the top N nodes in the preference list are good, the other nodes will not be used. But if all the N nodes are unavailable, the other nodes will be used. For write operation, this is called hinted handoff.
2. The diagram makes sense both for physical nodes and virtual nodes.

Comment: Please note that replication algorithm will skip positions in the ring to ensure that replication is made in different physical nodes, so it might not make real sense in case we talk about virtual nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't understand the part you're talking about.

Background:
My understanding of the paper is that, since Dynamo's default replication factor is 3, each node N is responsible for circle ranging from N-3 to N (while also being the coordinator to ring range N-1 to N).

That explains why:

> node B holds keys from F to B
> node C holds keys from G to C
> node D holds keys from A to D

And since range A-B falls within all those ranges, nodes B, C and D are the ones that have that range of key hashes.

The paper states:

> The section 4.3 Replication:
>
> To address this, the preference list for a key is constructed by skipping positions in the ring to ensure that the list contains only distinct physical nodes.

How can preference list contain more than N nodes if it is constructed by skipping virtual ones?
IMHO they should have stated something like this:

> To account for node failures, ring range N-3 to N may contain more than N nodes, N physical nodes plus x virtual nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed DBMS Dyanmo DB falls in that class which sacrifices Consistency. Refer to the image below:

[image]

So, the system is inconsistent even though it is highly available. Because network partitions are a given in Distributed Systems **you cannot not pick Partition Tolerance.**

Addressing your questions:

---

> 1. To account for node failures, preference list contains more than N nodes. I want to know why?

One fact of Large Scale Distributed Systems is that **in a system of thousands of nodes, failure of a nodes is a norm.**

You are bound to have a few nodes failing in such a big system. You don't treat it as an exceptional condition. You prepare for such situations. How do you prepare?

**For Data:** You simply replicate your data on multiple nodes.

**For Execution:** You perform the same execution on multiple nodes. This is called [speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution). As soon as you get the first result from the multiple executions you ran, you cancel the other executions.

That's the answer right there - you replicate your data to prepare for the case when node(s) may fail.

---

> 2. To account for node failures, preference list contains more than N nodes. Does this 'node' mean virtual node?

*I wanted to ensure that I always have access to my house. So I copied my house's keys and gave them to another family member of mine. This guy put those keys in a safe in our house. Now when we all go out, I'm under the illusion that we have other set of keys so in case I lose mine, we can still get in the house. But... those keys are in the house itself. Losing my keys simply means I lose the access to my house.* This is what would happen if we replicate the data on virtual nodes instead of physical nodes.

A virtual node is not a separate physical node and so when the real node on which this virtual node has been mapped to will fail, the virtual node will go away as well.

This 'node' cannot mean virtual node if the aim is high availability, which is the aim in Dynamo DB.